# PHP custom sorting

Tags: php

I'm trying to sort an array of values.

The possible values in the array are 'neg_infinity',... {real numbers},.., 'infinity'

```
<?php
$a = array(
  array('column' => 3),
  array('column' => -1),
  array('column' => 1),
  array('column' => .1),
  array('column' => 2),
  array('column' => 'infinity'),
  array('column' => 'neg_infinity'),
  array('column' => 'infinity'),
);
```

I want:

```
    $a = array(
      array('column' => 'neg_infinity'),
      array('column' => -1),
      array('column' => .1),
      array('column' => 1),
      array('column' => 2),
      array('column' => 3),
      array('column' => 'infinity'),
      array('column' => 'infinity'),
    );
```

I've been playing around with [uasort](https://www.php.net/uasort).

Anybody have a solution to his problem?

---

TEST DRIVER

```
<?php
function cmp($a, $b) {
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    if ($a == 'neg_infinity') {
        return -1;
    }
    if ($a == 'infinity') {
        return 1;
    }
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}

$a = array('a' => 'infinity', 'b' => 8, 'c' => -1,'e' => 2, 'f' => 5, 'g' => 3, 'h' => -4, 'd' => 'neg_infinity');


uasort($a, 'cmp');


var_dump($a);
```

Comment: What did you try? Post your example and we can probably tell you why you failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tricky bastard! I'll give you plus one because it took me 20 minutes to get it was an array of arrays.

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    if ($a['column'] == 'neg_infinity') {
        return -1;
    }
    if ($a['column'] == 'infinity') {
        return 1;
    }

    if ($b['column'] == 'neg_infinity') {
        return 1;
    }
    if ($b['column'] == 'infinity') {
        return -1;
    }
    if ($a['column'] == $b['column']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['column'] < $b['column']) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

it is tested: http://codepad.org/13GuICbH

IdeOne is too mainstream, ya know.

Comment: Thanks.  I forgot to check the $b values.

Comment: It slipped from me too at the beginning but at a certain point you're going to compare -1 and neg_infinity for sure and if you don't check $b you miss that comparison.

Answer (score 5):

Use this for your sorting function:

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    if ($a == 'neg_infinity') {
       return -1
    }
    if ($a == 'infinity') {
       return 1
    }
    return ($a < $b ? -1 : 1)
}
```

Comment: What if both $a and $b == 'infinity'?

Comment: Then the `a` value will take priority. If you want that to be different (or randomized), you'll have to add an extra clause to handle the case. It's the same if a == b, the a value will take priority.

Comment: I actually came up with this solution as well.  But it doesn't work.

Comment: Hm.. didn't notice you've actually got a multidimensional array. You'd want to use `if ($a['column'] == 'neg_infinity')` and the like instead. Otherwise you're directly comparing arrays to strings/integers, which'll fail.

Comment: @Marc B: you need to check $b too, otherwise you're gonna miss the comparison when 'infinity' is $b

Answer (score 5):

Something like this should work:

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    if ($a == 'neg_infinity') {
        return -1;
    }
    if ($a == 'infinity') {
        return 1;
    }
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

Comment: Do you really need the first conditional?

Comment: @animuson: Maybe not, but per the docs, "The comparison function must return an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if the first argument is considered to be respectively less than, equal to, or greater than the second."