# Custom sort in array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP custom sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7262783/php-custom-sorting)

I have an array,

```
Array
(
    [Flag]      =>  2
    [Pending]   => 11
    [Received]  => 11
    [Sent]      =>  8
    [Skip]      =>  5
    [Complaint] =>  1
    [Query]     =>  1
)
```

I have two requests for the above array:

1. How can I sort this into the order Received, Sent, Pending, Flag, Skip, Query, Request, Complaint.
2. As we see that "Request" is not available in the array, how do I push it into the array with the value zero?

Comment: What have you tried? I recommend you read about `usort()` which is User Defined sorting: http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Comment: to do sorting like thatyou have to do manually there is not any also for that

Comment: What way are you creating the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array = array
(
    "Flag" => 2
    "Pending" => 11
    "Received" => 11
    "Sent" => 8
    "Skip" => 5
    "Complaint" => 1
    "Query" => 1
);

$array["Request"] = 0;

function my_sort($a, $b) {
    $order = array("Received", "Sent", "Pending", "Flag", "Skip", "Query", "Request", "Complaint");
    return array_search($b, $order) - array_search($a, $order);
}

uksort($array, "my_sort");

print_r($array);
```

Comment: Thanks! that helped however it processed Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 1 [2] => 5 [3] => 8 [4] => 11 [5] => 11 [6] => 2 ) and values were lost... how can i maintain the values?

Comment: Ah, use `uksort` instead

Answer (score 0):

With the [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) function [usort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php), you can create a user-defined function and sort your array based on the results of this function.

Answer (score 0):

Try [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php), followed by,

```
$array['Request'] = 0;
```